# VBA: Cut a range of columns and paste it as one column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm pretty new and would greatly appreciate your help. I have data in 14000 columns that are about 30 lines each.

I need to paste each column underneath one another such that I will only have 1 column remaining. I have provided an example screenshot:

[image: Example of Data]

My attempt at the VBA code is as follows (which doesn't work):

```
Sub Cut()

Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 14000
  Col = Columns(i).Select

  Range("N2:N31").Offset(, i).Select
  Selection.Cut

  Range("H2").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Row.Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste

Next i

End Sub
```

Please Help. Thanks

Comment: Your current data starts in column 10 (or whatever) and you want to move it all to column 1 on the same sheet - is that right?

Comment: Are there any gaps in the data you are trying to copy into one row? You could iterate through a range by row, by cell storing the values into an array and then loop over the array writing out the values back to the sheet in the desired column.

Comment: @SJR, My Data starts in collumn 14 and spans to about collumn 14000 and yes I'd like to paste it all into one collumn

Comment: @QHarr, I'm trying to copy each collumn from collumn 14 to 14000 and paste it all into one collumn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of copying range you can just assign the values to range as

```
Sub ConvertRangeToColumn()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastColumn As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")  'change Sheet1 to yout data sheet
    With ws
        lastColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column   'get last column using Row 1
        For i = 5 To lastColumn             'loop though each column starting from 5
            Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, i), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row, i)) 'set range to copy
            .Range("A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count).Value = rng.Value
        Next i
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, which assumes your data start in row 1.

```
Sub Cut()

Dim c As Long

Application.screenupdating=false

For c = 14 To Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'change 1 if data starts in a different row
    Range(Cells(1, c), Cells(Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp)).Copy Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
Next c

Application.screenupdating=true

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**It will look something like this:**

```
Option Explicit
Sub MoveData()
    Dim i As Long, lRowData As Long, lRowInput As Long
    ' "H" is 8th column, so you might want
    ' to change starting value of i to 9 or something like that
    For i = 14 To 14000
        ' Last row in "H" column (where you paste data)
        lRowInput = Range("H" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ' Last row in i column (from where you draw data)
        lRowData = Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
        ' Copy values from i column to "H" column
        Range("H" & lRowInput + 1, "H" & lRowInput + lRowData - 1) = _
            Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(lRowData, i)).Value
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi AntiDrondert. Thanks so much for your help. I tried it out, but it didnt quite work :(. It ended up wiping the data in column H after each iteration.

Comment: @CodeMeARiver give me a sec, I'll fix it

Comment: @CodeMeARiver ok now?

Answer (score 0):

Especially for large amounts of data, you will often be better off (faster execution time), by reading the original data into a VBA Array; manipulating it; then writing it back to the worksheet, as compared with multiple read/writes to the worksheet.

Here is an example of using that somewhat different technique on your data, if I understand your data setup correctly (a contiguous range of data including `N2`, with no blanks, and all columns the same length).  *If my understanding of your data setup is incorrect, probably minor changes to the code will be necessary*

Also, this might not work in 32 bit Excel, but it is worth a try.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ManyIntoOneColumn()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim rWhatIHave As Range
    Dim rWhatIWant As Range
    Dim V As Variant, W As Variant
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long

'set worksheet
Set WS = Worksheets("sheet1") 'change worksheet name

'set range to copy.  If not contiguous, might have to do it differently
Set rWhatIHave = WS.Range("N2").CurrentRegion

'set first cell of WhatIWant
Set rWhatIWant = WS.Range("H2")

'read range into variant array
V = rWhatIHave

'dimension results array
ReDim W(1 To UBound(V, 1) * UBound(V, 2), 1 To 1)

'populate W
K = 0
For I = 1 To UBound(V, 2)
    For J = 1 To UBound(V, 1)
        K = K + 1
        W(K, 1) = V(J, I)
    Next J
Next I

'set rWhatIWant
Set rWhatIWant = rWhatIWant.Resize(rowsize:=UBound(W, 1), columnsize:=1)

'clear results range and write the values
With rWhatIWant
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = W
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Will keep in mind to use with Excel 64 bit.

Comment: @CodeMeARiver I would go ahead and try it with Excel 32 bit.  It may be well under the limits.